# class panels do bootstrap não está funcionando

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Eu intalei o framework bootstrap e testando alguns componentes do site alguns funcionaram e outros não e não sei o motivo, testei o dropdawn e jumbotron e os dois funcionaram, porém quando testei o panel ele não mostrou o que deveria, o codigo que peguei foi esse:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- As 3 meta tags acima *devem* vir em primeiro lugar dentro do `head`; qualquer outro conteúdo deve vir *após* essas tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim e Respond.js para suporte no IE8 de elementos HTML5 e media queries -->
    <!-- ALERTA: Respond.js não funciona se você visualizar uma página file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Olá, mundo!</h1>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
        Panel content
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        Panel content
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (obrigatório para plugins JavaScript do Bootstrap) -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Inclui todos os plugins compilados (abaixo), ou inclua arquivos separadados se necessário -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

O codigo saiu no navegodor como se tivesse sido escrito mesmo normal, sem nenhuma estilização, apenas o panel-title tava comum tamanho maior. Porque isso aconteceu? preciso instalar mais alguma coisa, eu uso o sublime text 3 para escrever e testei no mozilla e chrome.

Comment: Certifique-se que você está testando na versão correta do bootstrap. A versão 2 não tem panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente você não está usando a versão mais recente do bootstrap ou você não chamou corretamente o arquivo css. Veja aqui o seu código funcionando (apenas inclui o arquivo css e javascript diretamente do [Bootstrap CDN que pode ser visto aqui](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/):

[E neste link aqui você pode ver o seu código funcionando](http://codepen.io/wendell_chrys/pen/pEdoEa).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br"> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- As 3 meta tags acima *devem* vir em primeiro lugar dentro do `head`; qualquer outro conteúdo deve vir *após* essas tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim e Respond.js para suporte no IE8 de elementos HTML5 e media queries -->
    <!-- ALERTA: Respond.js não funciona se você visualizar uma página file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <body>
    <h1>Olá, mundo!</h1>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (obrigatório para plugins JavaScript do Bootstrap) -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Inclui todos os plugins compilados (abaixo), ou inclua arquivos separadados se necessário -->
     </body>
</html>
```